# Laravel Mail authentification trouble

Tags: laravel

Hi guys i need help with send code on email [laravel]

i recieve an email but without link and username like that

Hello username

Please activate your account using the following link

---

link

**Here is my code**

**activate.blade.php**
    Hello {{ 'username' }} 
Please activate your account using the following link
---
{{ 'link' }}

AccountController

```
<?php
```

class AccountController extends BaseController {

```
public function getCreate() {
    return View::make('account.create');
}

    public function postCreate() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                'email'          => 'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
                'username'       => 'required|max:20|min:3|unique:users',
                'password'       => 'required|min:6',
                'password_again' => 'required|same:password'

            )
        );

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('account-create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        } else {

            $email         = Input::get('email');
            $username  = Input::get('username');
            $password  = Input::get('password');

            //Activation code
            $code       = str_random(60);

            $user = User::create(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => Hash::make($password),
                'code' => $code,
                'active' => 0
            ));

            if($user) {

                Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'username' => $username), function($message) use ($user) {
                    $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate your account');
                });

                return Redirect::route('home')
                        ->with('global', 'Your account has been created! We have sent you an email to activate your account.');
            }
        }

    }

        public function getActivate($code) {

        }


}
```

**Home controller**

```
<?php
```

class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function home()  {

```
    Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('name' => 'NoReply'), function($message){
        $message->to('noreply@bla.com', 'Noreply')->subject('Noreplymail');
    });
    return View::make('home');

}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your **activate.blade.php** try:

```
Hello {{ $username }} <br>

Please activate your account using the following link <br>

--- <br>

{{ $link }}
```

Comment: Emm? Can you explain your comment a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, this is a HTML template driven by blade.  And there is no HTML your code.

Comment: Edited. Is it looks better now?

Comment: I edited it for you but you should know that a View is an HTML document that contains HTML tags

Comment: when i change to Hello {{ $username }} <br>

Please activate your account using the following link <br>

--- <br>

{{ $link }} I get error Undefined variable: username (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/emails/auth/activate.blade.php)

Comment: and when i change code like that Hello {{{ $username }}} <br><br>
Please activate your account using the following link<br><br>
---<br>
{{{ $link }}}<br> i receive email with link and username but i get same error  Undefined variable: username (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/emails/auth/activate.blade.php) please assist me.

Comment: You need to edit your HomeController. You are sending there only 'name' => 'NoReply'. But your view require $username and $link.